# Trigger multiple targets at once

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp, bazelrc

I have multiple `cc_binary` targets which will be build independently to create elf files.
I want to have single target command to build all at once to avoid multiple triggers and add the post build rule to copy all the required elf and other build files to a target folder in the Bazel.

Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can build multiple targets via:

```
bazel build -- //folder:target1 //folder:target2 //folder:targetN
```

or

```
bazel build -- //folder:... -//folder:some_excluded_target
```

Have also a look at [rules_multirun](https://github.com/keith/rules_multirun).

You can also make a kind of "virtual" binary that only has dependencies

```
cc_shell/cc_binary( 
   name = "build_targets",
   data = ["//folder:target1", "//folder:target2", "//folder:target3"],
)
```

And then just build "build_targets":

```
bazel build -- //:build_targets
```

Maybe also [rules_pkg](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg) can help you do fetch together different binary an put them in an archive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using a `filegroup` target, see https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#filegroup. This is kind-of a misnomer, but it explicitly says "collection of targets" and not "collection of files".